# How to draw flowchart from javascript code

Tags: javascript, flowchart

How can i draw a flowchart from the javascript code.
here is the code example which one i want to draw a flowchart.
any idea how can i draw it

```
if (data.length > 0) {
    var messages = [];
    for (message of data) {
        var isDuplicate = false;
        for (thread of self.topic) {
            if (message.id == thread.id) {
                isDuplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isDuplicate) {
            messages.unshift(message);
        }
    }
    if (messages.length > 0) {
        for (message of messages) {
            self.topic.push(message);
        }
    }
    self.lastMessageTimestamp = data.timestamp;
}
```

Comment: please paste your code into your question, instead of linking an image of it.

Comment: i paste the code already